# Custom Primary Key Names

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to customize the Primary Key names in the SQL that gets generated by EF. I've already customized the Foreign Keys successfully by stripping off the schema name. However, when I use the same technique for the Primary Keys, it doesn't appear to work.

Here's the generator class I'm using:

```
public class KeyNamingGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(DropForeignKeyOperation dropForeignKeyOperation)
    {
        dropForeignKeyOperation.Name = StripSchema(dropForeignKeyOperation.Name);
        base.Generate(dropForeignKeyOperation);
    }

    protected override void Generate(DropPrimaryKeyOperation dropPrimaryKeyOperation)
    {
        dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Name = StripSchema(dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Name);
        base.Generate(dropPrimaryKeyOperation);
    }

    protected override void Generate(AddForeignKeyOperation addForeignKeyOperation)
    {
        addForeignKeyOperation.Name = StripSchema(addForeignKeyOperation.Name);
        base.Generate(addForeignKeyOperation);
    }

    protected override void Generate(AddPrimaryKeyOperation addPrimaryKeyOperation)
    {
        addPrimaryKeyOperation.Name = StripSchema(addPrimaryKeyOperation.Name);
        base.Generate(addPrimaryKeyOperation);
    }

    private string StripSchema(string name)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(name, @"(?<=_)[a-zA-Z]*\.", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }
}
```

The Foreign Key related Generate methods work fine, but the ones related to Primary Keys don't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that AddPrimaryKeyOperation only works when you are adding a PK independently of table creation. On a whim I decided to dig into CreateTableOperation and it has a PrimaryKey property that you can manipulate.

Here is the completed code:

```
    protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
    {
        createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.Name = StripSchema(createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.Name);
        base.Generate(createTableOperation);
    }
```

The few examples of how to use SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator that are out there don't really address this distinction.